# Change Link Text to Image Using CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to change a text link on my site to an image using css...need some help please. Below you will see my css - I would like to change my favorite text http://cl.ly/0S2j28082G2W423Y2T00 to an image.

```
a.upb_add_bookmark {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E8BD61;
    border-color: #C79324;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: black;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your background property will need to be set to include the image. You will also need to set the `<a>` element as an `inline-block` so that you can declare a height and width for it.

```
a.upb_add_bookmark {
 background: url('favorites-image.jpg') no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 51px;
 width: 92px;
}
```

Thats how you can display an image without actually using an `<img>` tag; nothing but css.

Comment: +1 this was originally voted down but seems like the exact solutions you would look for in this case.  Are we misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Thanks but this did not work...First it repeated my small icon several times...I just need one and it did not replace my link...it went on top of my link... this is the code used to generate my favorites link...like I said this is a plugin that is for bookmarking posts...$bookmark = upb_bookmark_controls($add_text = 'Favorites', $delete_text = 'Remove Favorite', $wrapper = true);
$meta_output .= str_replace( '<div class="upb_add_remove_links">', '<span class="upb_add_remove_links">', str_replace( '</div>', '</span>', $bookmark ) );

Comment: Wasn't the whole point of this problem to make the text actual html markup rather than just embedded in the image?  Looks like when I voted up I didn't realize that the text was still part of the image.  My bad.

Comment: To address the repeating issue, please refer to the correction in my answer [background: url('image' no-repeat);]. Also, plan to position the image by using the background-position property.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://www.site.com"><img src="image.png" alt="Favorite icon" /></a>
```

or

```
    a {
    background-image: url('image.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    }
    <a href="http://www.site.com"></a>
```

Personally I would use the first one because the image is part of the structure and not a design element and CSS deals with design.

Answer (score 0):

*A very simple way to fix this problem*

** 1. Create a div element that will encapsulate this image **

** 2. Add CSS in order to set that background of this div to be the image.  (See code below).  In this example the class name of your div will be called 'button'

```
       .button
        {
            backgroundimage:url('http://cl.ly/0S2j28082G2W423Y2T00/Screen%20Shot%202012-02-09%20at%2012.02.45%20PM.png');
            height: 50px;
            width: 92px;
        }

        .button a
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 50px;
        }
```

- Revise the Html *

**Put the text you want to display into the aforementioned div with the class name 'button'**

```
    <div class="button">

        <span>Favorite (1)</span>

    </div>
```

*** This will allow you to select the actual text while still maintaning the background  ***

Here is the complete version source with my modification for your reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en">
  <head>

    <style>

        .button
        {
            background-image:url('http://cl.ly/0S2j28082G2W423Y2T00/Screen%20Shot%202012-02-09%20at%2012.02.45%20PM.png');
            height: 50px;
            width: 92px;
        }

        .button a
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 50px;
        }

    </style>

    <title>Screen Shot 2012-02-09 at 12.02.45 PM.png</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" name="viewport">

    <meta content="CloudApp" name="author">

    <link href="http://assets.cld.me/1325250420/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">

    <!--[if (!IE)|(gte IE 8)]><!-->
<link href="http://assets.cld.me/1325250420/assets/viso-datauri.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="http://assets.cld.me/1325250420/assets/viso.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

    <script src="http://assets.cld.me/1325250420/assets/viso.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://assets.cld.me/1325250420/assets/ie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body id="image">
    <header id="header">

    <h1><a href="http://store.getcloudapp.com/">Simple sharing</a></h1>


  <h2>Screen Shot 2012-02-09 at 12.02.45 PM.png</h2>

  <a class="embed" href="http://cl.ly/0S2j28082G2W423Y2T00/Screen%20Shot%202012-02-09%20at%2012.02.45%20PM.png">Direct link</a>
</header>

<section id="content">

    <div class="button">

        <span>Favorite (1)</span>

    </div>

</section>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gauges = _gauges || [];
      (function() {
        var t   = document.createElement('script');
        t.type  = 'text/javascript';
        t.async = true;
        t.id    = 'gauges-tracker';
        t.setAttribute('data-site-id', '4ea557ec613f5d39e7000002');
        t.src = '//secure.gaug.es/track.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can see the site here http://bit.ly/wEnQPv  - You must login to view (Love) text - username: demo, password: demo12

Comment: @Eddie,  the love(1) looks like what you want where the text is markup and the background is a solid color.  What exactly is the question regarding my example? Sorry I'm a bit confused

Answer (score -1):

```
a.upb_add_bookmark {
background: url('image.png') no-repeat;
border:none;
width: 92px;
height: 51px;
color: transparent;
padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

This code works for me

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?

Comment: Nice touch adding `color: transparent` to hide the text overlayed on top of the background image. You need to add the `display: block` or `display: inline-block` since anchor tags do not have hold dimensions in the box model.